# Python: Extract Seperated Text from HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html

I have the following HTML repeated several times on a page (please do not judge):

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#" title="#" class="#">
        <img src="img.jpg" alt="#" class="#">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <a href="#">
          <h4 class="h4-class">{TITLE}</h4>
        {SOME TEXT 1}<br />
        <h5><img src="img.jpg" alt="#" /> {SOME TEXT 2}</h5>
        {SOME TEXT 3}      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like to extract `{TITLE}`, `{SOME TEXT 1}`, `{SOME TEXT 2}` and `{SOME TEXT 3}`

My code is as follows:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('text')
soup = bs(html)
divs = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "text" })

for div in divs:
    inner_text = div.text
    strings = inner_text.split("\n")
    print strings[0] ## I want this to print just {TITLE}
```

On printing it out, it prints one line connecting all the values e.g.

`{TITLE}{SOME TEXT 1}{SOME TEXT 2}{SOME TEXT 3}`

Is there anyway around this? What have I missed?

Comment: I do not see any `list_txt` in the given HTML code.

Comment: Typo when adding it here. The problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `prettify` ([see documentation here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing)) the div content first and then manipulate each line as needed. This will work if the divs with class name `text` have same structure.

**Code (Python 2):**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#" title="#" class="#">
        <img src="img.jpg" alt="#" class="#">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <a href="#">
          <h4 class="h4-class">{TITLE}</h4>
        {SOME TEXT 1}<br />
        <h5><img src="img.jpg" alt="#" /> {SOME TEXT 2}</h5>
        {SOME TEXT 3}      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
'''
soup = bs(html)
divs = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"text"})
for div in divs:
    pretty_div = div.prettify()
    content_list = pretty_div.split("\n")
    content_list = [s.strip() for s in content_list]
    print content_list[3]
    print content_list[5]
    print content_list[9]
    print content_list[11]
```

**Output:**

```
{TITLE}
{SOME TEXT 1}
{SOME TEXT 2}
{SOME TEXT 3}
```

Comment: Let's say I wanted to extract the HREF, how would I go about in this scenario?

Comment: Do you want to extract only `href` attribute value of the links inside div of `text` class?